# Google Nearby Connections - How to send large data string using stream?

Tags: android, inputstream, google-nearby

I tried to send a string to another device with the stream. When I send a string with 60k characters, it works fine and always success received the stream. But when I try to send 70k characters or larger, it always failed and the device got disconnected.

```
SimpleArrayMap<Long, Payload> incomingPayloads = new SimpleArrayMap<>();

@Override
public void onPayloadReceived(String endpointId, Payload payload) {
    switch (payload.getType()) {
         case Payload.Type.STREAM:
             // Add it to the tracking list so we can update it.
             incomingPayloads.put(payload.getId(), payload);
             break;
    }
}

@Override
public void onPayloadTransferUpdate(String endpointId, PayloadTransferUpdate update) {
    switch (update.getStatus()) {
        case PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.IN_PROGRESS:
            long size = update.getTotalBytes();
            if (size == -1) {
                // This is a stream payload, so we don't need to update anything at this point.
                return;
            }
            break;
        case PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.SUCCESS:
            // SUCCESS always means that we transferred 100%.
            Toast.makeText(this, "Transfer success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        case PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.FAILURE:
        case PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.CANCELED:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Transfer failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            // Unknown status.
break;
    }
```

Here is how I send the payload:

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(text.getBytes()); 
Payload payload = Payload.fromStream(stream); 
for (String endPointId : connectedIdList) { 
      connectionsClient 
          .sendPayload( endPointId, payload );
}
```

Comment: Can you include the call to sendPayload too?

Comment: Ok...I already updated the question sir
still don't know what the reason I failed.

Comment: Can you look for the "NearbyConnections" tag inside logcat for me? I reproduced your code (using a ByteArrayInputStream to send 70KB+ bytes), and I didn't get disconnected.

Comment: thanks for concern
In the end, I use ParcelFileDescriptor.createPipe() to solve the problem and its works great